# Sort a set of numbers when a sorted superset is available

Tags: algorithm, sorting

- I have a set A = {5,4,2,8}
- I have a set B = {1,2,4,5,7,8,9} which is sorted
- A is given to be a subset of B

I want to sort A (possibly using B (or even with some reasonable preprocessing)).  In general, I want to be able to sort many such arbitrary "As" (all subsets of B) for a given B. What is the best time in which this can be achieved?

Two naive solutions come to mind.

- Sort A independently (O(A log A))
- Scan B and take elements that appear in A (O(B)).

When A is small, the first is clearly better, when A is almost as large as B, the second is better. However, when, say B has something like 10^10 elements and A has 10^5, can we do better than either of these methods?

Comment: How does knowing B in that case help? it is like knowing that the natural order 1, 2, 3 ... infinity is sorted. The question is somewhat reduced to `when to use Quick sort vs Counting sort`.

Comment: For numbers with fixed length, e.g. 64 bits, you can also use radix sort and then it is O(A).

Comment: @PhamTrung The difference must lie in the fact that B is finite (much smaller) than the total order over all natural numbers. In fact, if B = A, you can just do an O(A) = O(B) scan, which you can't do even knowing the natural order.

Comment: The question is just another form of `when to use Quick sort vs Counting sort`. `O(10^10) > O( 10^5 log 10^5)`. What else you can do? `B` is just the space of the problem, am I right?

Comment: No, B may not contain a contiguous set of numbers. It is an arbitrary superset. The question is what else can be done.

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, it is unclear how your second solution achieves *O*(|*B*|). As you scan *B*, how do you "take elements that appear in *A*"? It sounds like there should be a log *A* factor somewhere.

The best I can contribute is an offline algorithm that sorts many *A*'s in *O*(|*B*| + *L*) where *L* is the sum of the lengths of all *A*'s. By "offline" I mean you can read all the *A*'s in advance.

1. Preprocess *B* and build a hash table mapping values in *B* to their positions. For your example the hash table is (1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 4 -> 3, 5 -> 4, 7 -> 5, 8 -> 6, 9 -> 7).
2. Store a linked list for every element in *B*, initially empty.
3. Scan all the *A*'s. If *A_i*[*j*] = *k*, then append *i* to the linked list of *k*. We can quickly find the linked list of *k* (aka the position of *k* in *B*) using the hash table. In your example, assuming *A* is the first vector we read from the input, and since *A*_1[4] = 8, we append 1 to the linked list of 8 in *B*.
4. Flush the *A* arrays.
5. Scan *B* and push elements into the *A* arrays. For example, if the linked list of 8 contains the values 1, 4 and 20, push a value of 8 in the 1st, 4th and 20th array.

In practical terms, this is a memory hog. Your constraint of 10^10 64-bit number already assumes 80 GB available RAM. The hash table requires at least triple that amount. Storing all the *A*'s in memory and the linked lists also require at least 3 *L* 64-bit values.

I am very skeptical that a practical online algorithm exists that makes good use of *B* to process one *A* at a time. Even assuming that you can look up positions in *B* in O(1) (e.g. with a hash table), that narrows the domain of your elements in *A* from 64 bits to 34 (10^10 rounded up). So counting sort is still unusable, since the final step requires scanning the domain of 10^10 values to sort a 10^5-element array. What the offline algorithm does is essentially pay off for the huge scan by sorting all the arrays at once.

Comment: Your comment is correct -- there does seem to be a log A hiding somewhere. Your answer works well when we know all the As in advance and in that case it as much of a memory hog as just the combined size of B and all As. I think that is a good tradeoff. This helps!